# Azure Service Fabric error: Access is denied. Failed to deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have created demo project of ***`Service Fabric`*** using Visual Studio. But I am unable to start. I have installed required ***`SDK`*** already.

Here is the output when I try to run the project.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Stateful1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Stateful1 -> C:\Users\Bimal.das\source\repos\Application4\Stateful1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\win7-x64\Stateful1.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: Application4, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>------ Deploy started: Project: Application4, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>Started executing script 'GetApplicationExistence'.
3>Finished executing script 'GetApplicationExistence'.
3>Time elapsed: 00:00:00.0135860
3>Access is denied
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Please find the [link here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YesYAPtyo89rlB9E3Fz8-6CG5I9zilHy/view?usp=sharing) what I tried so far.

Troubleshooting I have tried.

1. *Run Visual Studio in Save mode*
2. *Created Visual Studio Activity Log*
3. *Reinstalling Service Fabric Cluster*
4. *Reinstalling Visual Studio Community 2017*

Comment: Try delete bin\debug folder and clean and rebuild again and there is problem Access is  denied , probably run VS as administrator.

Comment: What does the Output Window show for the failed deploy?

Comment: @mjwills only mentioned error of the question. Only this much info I have

Comment: As @IPKaal mentioned, make sure you are running VS as an admin. Are you?

Comment: @Micah_MSFT ya. I am running as Admin

Comment: @Micah_MSFT I am using VS community 2017

Comment: Do you already have a cluster up an running or are you allowing VS to build the cluster for you? You might try opening Service Fabric Explorer and selecting to build a blank cluster first. Then once you confirm the cluster is up and running try publishing to it. That way VS only has to publish and not build the cluster. Might help.

Comment: Try to deploy the SF Project using a different [`Application Debug Mode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio#application-debug-mode), Maybe set to *Remove Application* or other option.

Comment: @DiegoMendes I tried all options. Still not working.

Comment: You should probably update the question with more information then, there is not enough information to give any more help!

Comment: @DiegoMendes I have edited the question. Can you check the link ?

Comment: what happens if you run this in PowerShell? `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster localhost:19000`

Comment: You're deploying to an Azure cluster, right? And the port you're deploying to is open in Azure?

Comment: @SJade no. I am trying to open it in local cluster node 1

Comment: Set the SF project as stratup and then just hit the run button

Comment: I referred the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster and now I am able to publish my own apps using power-shell but not from Visual studio  . :D

Answer (score 2):

- see

  - [Fabric Node open failed with error code = E_ACCESSDENIED · Issue #1056 · Azure/service-fabric-issues](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1056)
- I tried it working I'cant replicate the error
- check your firewall and windows event viewer

Comment: Did not work. I think there are some permission related issue for visual studio service fabric builder.

Comment: I referred the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster and now I am able to publish my own apps. :D